# Unable to access NDK module in emulator

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I'm using Android studio 1.0.2 to generate the `.so` library. When I load the app on the emulator, there is an error loading the module. The error message is:

`dlopen failed: library "HelloJNI" not found`

Here is my 
`MainActivity.java:`

```
public native String HelloJNI();

static
{
    System.load("HelloJNI");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(HelloJNI());
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

`HelloJNI.c`

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_linda_myapplication_MainActivity_HelloJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI");
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.linda.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    ndk{
        moduleName "HelloJNI"
        //cFlags "-DANDROID_NDK -D_DEBUG DNULL=0"   // Define some macros
        //ldLibs "EGL", "GLESv3", "dl", "log"       // Link with these libraries!
        //stl "stlport_shared"                      // Use shared stlport library
    }
}
sourceSets.main
        {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
productFlavors{
            x86{
                    ndk{
                                abiFilter "x86"
                    }
            }
            armv7a{
                        ndk{
                                    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
                        }
                    }
        }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: I check on apk file. It looks like the .so has been packed in to a folder named "lib/armeabi-v7a". But why the program failed to target the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the full path name of your library when use the call `System.load()`.

But if you use `System.loadLibrary()` to load the native library, the framework's implementation will search your library name in the values specified from `java.library.path` and environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem myself.

System.load("HelloJNI");

This is the point to make apk fail loading.

System.loadLibrary("HelloJNI");

This is the correct function. Code completing is awesome, but sometimes may people stupid:)